# I'm trying to create a Universal Pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to make a master pipeline which I'm trying to create for all the repositories.

I created a repo and it has 2 files.
.gitlab-ci.yaml and variables.yml

In the gitlab-ci.yml file I Include the variables.yml file with this command:

```
include:
   - local: 'variables.yml'
```

Example variables.yml file

```
variables:
   path/to_repo_in_/my_gitlab
     port: "${CI_PROJECT_ID}0"
   path/to_repo_in_/my_gitlab
     port: "${CI_PROJECT_ID}00"
```

The lines `path/to_repo_in_/my_gitlab` indicate the unique path to each repository as they are located from the root in my gitlab configured on my server.
And the value of the variable port, they must be different, that’s why I’m trying to make a unique value for a variable named port for each repository.

When I push .gitlab-ci.yaml and variables.yml to the master repo (that’s what we’ll call the main repository), gitlab complains about the syntax in the variables.yaml file

Please tell me how to bypass or solve the problem. I need to explicitly set a value for a variable for a specific repository. Since they are the same in all my repositories, they differ only in small values.

I tried setting values in the variables.yaml file in different ways, but unfortunately my options did not work